# python regex for < and first space

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This is html-

```
html_tag = <div class="profile-content large-9 columns end clearfix">
<h3>whatever</h3>
</div>
```

first i am converting in to a string like `str(html_tag.encode('utf-8'))`
Then i need that tag name.

```
print re.search('<(.+?) ',str(html_tag.encode('utf-8'))).group(1)
```

Here output will be 'div' only. basically i am taking substring between '<' and white space. But i am getting error of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.  So `re.search('<(.+?) ',str(html_tag.encode('utf-8')))` did not match anything. Now How can i correct this regex?

Comment: What is `html_tag`?

Comment: Do you know about BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that your "html_tag" is in tags.txt file so I can read it with following code into a str

```
with open("tags.txt") as file:            
    data = file.read()
```

Then you can match div tag with following

```
matched = re.match(r'<(.+?)\s', data)
print(matched.group(1))
div
```

here "\s" is to match white spaces.

Comment: Bold assumption about `html_tag`. Also OP is using Python 2.7 not Python 3.

Comment: That was a bit hastily written, I didn't mean in relation to Python 2.7. I meant in relation to you using `re.match()` you need to use `re.search()`.